# symfony3 REST API issue with yml routing using FOSRestBundle

Tags: symfony, routes, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.3

I've finally got my first API in Symfony3 which is actually working.
Very well so far but problems came when I tried using `YML` configs for routing instead of `annotation`. It is driving me crazy because it seems to work, in fact when I chance for eg the controller name, it gives me an internal server error but, when everything is "correct", it seems it's unable to find the method in my controller.
So here is my code:

General routing settings

```
#config/routing.yml
user_routes:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/user_routes.yml"
    type: rest
```

Bundle routing settings

```
#AppBundle/Resources/config/user_routes.yml
user:
    type: rest
    resource: AppBundle\Controller\UserController
```

And finally my controller:

```
   <?php

    namespace AppBundle\Controller;

    use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
    use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
    use AppBundle\Entity\User;


    class UserController extends FOSRestController
    {

    //    /**
    //     * @Rest\Get("/user")
    //     */
        public function getAction()
        {
            $restresult = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:User')->findAll();
            if ($restresult === null) {
                return new View("there are no users exist", Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
            }

            return $restresult;
        }
}
```

Using `annotation` it works well and everybody's happy but when I use these settings I get a 404. I tried adding `prefix: /api` and `name_prefix:  api_` according to Symfony official documentation but it didn't work.
I tried also adding a `defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Controller:UserController:get` but error 404 was always round the corner.
As I said, if I change the name of the controller class in the `user_routes.yml`, I get a 500 error so it seems the routing is being read but it's evident that something is missing here and I'm unable to find it neither on the official documentation nor in other places.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the action from this:

```
public function getAction()
```

to this:

```
public function getUsersAction()
```

[DOCUMENTATION](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work but trying with ``getUserAction`` I get an error: ``Call to a member function has() on null</p>.... ``

Comment: can you please tell me which route are you trying to view? http://yoursite.com/users ?

Comment: The route is ``domain/user``

Comment: you need to change the route to domain/users because if you want to you rest api you need to follow its rules

Comment: Just done but I get this error Error: ``Call to a member function has() on null``

Comment: this is another error, where do you retrieve this error? line of code?

Answer (score 0):

Well, just in case it may become useful for someone, I found the solution.
The problem lay in the `yml` `user_routes.yml`.
Here is the correct configuration:

```
path: /user
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:get }
requirements:
    _method: GET
```

That's it ;)